# Along side Roman roads, where did the drainage ditches lead?

Tags: roman-empire, construction, engineering

Reading about how Roman roads were built, it seems they built drainage ditches on both sides. I've found various sites talking about this, such as [this one](https://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/ancient-rome/roman-roads/).

This leads to a question that will sound trivial at first. Where did these ditches lead?

Did they stay parallel to the road forever? In that case I don't see how they would help with drainage at all. They need to lead to a large body of water.

So for example, as a road approached a town, did the ditches also follow the road right into town? That seems impossible, but if they terminated at the town border, then where does that lead except nowhere?

Or, as a road moved away from a town, did the ditches follow it even uphill? If so then we have drainage flowing back towards town and then terminating right at the town. Sounds like a recipe for flooding the town.

So the obvious guess is that other canals were dug to intersect the ditches and then lead to a lake/river/sea. **But I have never been able to find mention of such canals.** And I've never found a map of roads that include the ditches in the first place.

(I know the Romans built some canals. What I'm saying here is I can't find any mention of canals connecting to drainage ditches of a road.)

Maybe I have some fundamental misunderstanding about how drainage ditches work? I thought they must lead to a big body of water. But maybe they are more like shallow wells that allow the water to seep down into the ground (down to the tablewater) more quickly? That seems hard to believe though. That sounds like it would quickly fill up during rain and then be useless.

So just to emphasize where I'm coming from... The whole idea of roads and waterworks having to work together is confusing or at least disheartening. It would seem to severely limit **where and what path** you can built a road. That's why I wonder if these drainage ditches worked in some other way.

Comment: This would be more suited to construction SE, if there was such a thing. Modern roads still have drainage ditches. They are usually not paved and the water running off from the road will either just seep into the earth or (if there is really a lot of rain) be discharged somewhere into the surrounding countryside. There really is no reason why these ditches should have to lead to any body of water.

Comment: e.g. here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civil-engineering

Comment: @Jan I could ask how drainage ditches work there, but the question here is asking where they lead which I feel is on topic. I explained my reasoning because otherwise it would seem a trivial question. I feel like it's in general a good idea to explain your reasoning with a question even tho it can get you in trouble sometimes.

Comment: I kind of agree, but as it stands the question looks a bit like "Why did Roman spinning tops not just fall over?" (which would be more suited to physics stack exchange).The basic problems that required road drainage in antiquity were quite similar to those of today (except aquaplaning), and the typical solutions from today are simple and obvious enough to have already been used in antiquity.

Comment: Drainage ditches - whether they were built by Romans, or modern engineers - lead downhill, because that's the way water flows.   At convenient points, they direct the water away from the road, into ponds, streams, or just into open land that happens to be lower than the ditch at that point.  For instance, the drainage ditch by my house (which lies on a moderately sloping road) runs downhill along the road for several hundred yards/meters, then empties into a stream.

Comment: Each and every time a road must bridge some waterway, it is clearly pointless to "*gutter*" the drainage water over the waterway. Instead, the drainage ditch is emptied into the waterway. This is always possible because the level of the road must be higher than the waterway water level (outside seasonal flooding season at least - when it is irrelevant) in order for the road to be usable. At times, such as in Dutch polders, this may necessitate building the road on a dike.

Comment: It's a good question, but you better ask this in an engineering stack.

Comment: The drainage ditch next to a road is something akin to the rain gutter of a roof: a conventient way to control water flow. The drainage ditches are no waterways or canals.

Comment: While the engineering aspect might be better in the engineering stack, part of the question is also how the Romans actually did design the ditches, e.g if there are data or maps from archaeological excavations or surveys that show real examples. That aspect seems quite on topic for history stack exchange.